# Why is the memory view of a numpy record readonly?

Tags: python, swig, memoryview

Why is Python telling me that the memory view of a record is readonly?

```py
>>> x = np.zeros(1, dtype='d,d,i')
>>> x
array([(0., 0., 0)], dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<i4')])
>>> memoryview(x).readonly
False
>>> memoryview(x[0]).readonly
True
```

Obviously, `x[0]` isn't readonly, since

```
>>> x[0][0] += 1
>>> x[0]
(1., 0., 0)
```

Memory view doesn't have trouble with normal arrays:

```
>>> y = np.zeros((3, 4))
>>> memoryview(y).readonly
False
>>> memoryview(y[0]).readonly
False
```

Likewise, the deprecated `__array_info__` knows that `x[0]` is read-write:

```
>>> x.__array_interface__['data']   # returns tuple (address, read-only)
(105553143159680, False)
>>> x[0].array_interface__['data']
(105553143159680, False)
```

My actual issue is in C code. Fortunately all my issues there can also be shown in pure Python.

I'm trying to read and write numpy records in C code, and I just need the address of the data. I can find the address of the data just fine using [`__array_interface__`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html) and its corresponding C-side `__array_struct__`. But there is a note on that page saying that this is legacy, and that new code should be using the buffer protocol.

But the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects) (which is [mimicked](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html) by `memoryview` in Python) thinks the record is read-only. I have to specifically ask for a readonly buffer. Yes, I could get the address of the data from the "readonly" buffer, and write to it anyway, but that feels dirty.

---

Updated to respond to @tdelaney's comment:

As an experiment, I wrote a small C function that requested a read-only memory buffer, found the start address, and incremented the double there even though it wasn't supposed to.

```
void foo(PyObject *object) {
    Py_buffer view;
    PyObject_GetBuffer(object, &view, PyBUF_CONTIG_RO);
    if (view.obj) {
        double *data = (double *)view.buf;
        *data += 1;
    }
    PyBuffer_Release(&view);
}
```

I could then look at the resulting array in Python.

For arrays of records, both `foo(x)` and `foo(x[1])` correctly incremented an array element.

For the two-dimensional array of doubles, both `foo(y)` and `foo(y[1])` correctly incremented an array element.  As expected, `foo(y[1][2])` did nothing.

So for records, the `np.void` is *not* copied.  At least in the case.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but you can take a slice of one variable across all records, and *that* is writable. e.g. `memoryview(x['f0'])` is writeable.

Comment: `memoryview` _does_ have trouble with normal arrays if you reference all the way down to a cell instead of an entire row. `memoryview(y[0][0]).readonly` is `True`. Numpy created a `np.float64` and copied the cell value. Its not a reference to the original memory, hence a copy and hence read only. The same thing is happening here. `x[0]` is `np.void` and the record has presumably been copied. I can't find anything definitive on this so making it a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @tdelaney.  See comments added to my original post.  The `np.void` record, at least in this case, has not been copied. Your explanation was certainly plausible, and is almost certainly the reason this case is implemented incorrectly.

Comment: Untested hypothesis: maybe zeros gives you a zero initialised array that's meant to be using copy on write semantics under the hood some how?

Comment: @Flexo. Same problem happens if I use np.ones() or np.empty().  Most likely, the issue is as tdelaney points out: When you get down to the cell level, it gets confused.